# While trying to iterate over the data from Shazam API, I get a "data.map is not a function

Tags: react-redux, rapidapi

[While trying to iterate over the data from Shazam API, I get a "data.map is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfH5u.png)" error. Console.log(data) returns the array of 20 objects (tracks). Any ideas why I get the error? error. Console.log(data) returns the array of 20 objects (tracks). Any ideas why I get the error?

Comment: On line 20 where is genres defined?

Comment: Is useGetTopChartsQuery something you created? If so you need to check if data is not an array inside of useGetTopChartsQuery and return an empty array. If not I think this check will work in the return `data?.length && data.map`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
data.tracks?.map
```

instead of:

```
data?.map
```